# How do you sum up similar data in a csv using plotly and pandas python libraries?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sum, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a graph using pandas to read a csv file and plotly to create a bar chart in Python.

The csv data looks something like this (this isn't the correct data, its an example):

```
day,month,year,cases,deaths,countriesAndTerritories
11,11,2020,190,230, United_States_of_America
10,11,2020,224,132, United_States_of_America
9,11,2020,80,433, United_States_of_America
8,11,2020,126,623, United_States_of_America
```

I've successfully created a bar chart that visualizes deaths per month using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

covid_data = pd.read_csv('data/data.csv')

united_states_data = covid_data[covid_data.countriesAndTerritories == 'United_States_of_America']

month_data = united_states_data[['month']]

death_data = united_states_data[['deaths']]

fig = px.bar(united_states_data, x='month', y='deaths', title='COVID-19 deaths by month')
fig.show()
```

[image]

The problem is for each month it stacks the data from each day on top of each other and shows white lines separating the days. I only want the data for each month, I don't care about the days. How would I go about this? I figured I would have to somehow create a new dataset for the total deaths of each month by adding the data from each of the days in the same months together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should achieve your purpose:

```
df_plot = df.groupby('month', as_index=False).deaths.sum()
fig = px.bar(df_plot, x='month', y='deaths', title='COVID-19 deaths by month')
fig.show()
```

Comment: You'd need to group by month, year, and country, yes?

Comment: If there is more than a year and a target-contry in the analysis, yes! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This is much better than what I did to fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found a solution that groups the days of each month together to create a monthly death toll.

```
# create a dict that holds the data I want (set deaths to 0 for now)
monthly_deaths = [
    {"month": 1, "name": 'January', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 2, "name": 'February', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 3, "name": 'March', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 4, "name": 'April', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 5, "name": 'May', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 6, "name": 'June', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 7, "name": 'July', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 8, "name": 'August', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 9, "name": 'September', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 10, "name": 'October', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 11, "name": 'November', "deaths": 0},
    {"month": 12, "name": 'December', "deaths": 0},
]

# create a data frame of the data I want to use to achieve this
new_data = pd.DataFrame(united_states_data)

# iterate through the rows of the data frame and update the values of the dict
for i, j in new_data.iterrows():
    if float(j[['month']]) == 1:
        monthly_deaths[0]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 2:
        monthly_deaths[1]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 3:
        monthly_deaths[2]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 4:
        monthly_deaths[3]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 5:
        monthly_deaths[4]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 6:
        monthly_deaths[5]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 7:
        monthly_deaths[6]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 8:
        monthly_deaths[7]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 9:
        monthly_deaths[8]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 10:
        monthly_deaths[9]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 11:
        monthly_deaths[10]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])
    if float(j[['month']]) == 12:
        monthly_deaths[11]['deaths'] += int(j[['deaths']])

# plot the data
fig = px.bar(monthly_deaths, x='name', y='deaths', title='COVID-19 deaths by month')
fig.show()
```

The result is this:
[image]